# Combining two unique numbers (order doesn't matter) to create a unique number

Tags: logic, algebra

I'm creating a website in which 2 items out of a possible 117 are chosen and compared in different ways.  I need a way to assign each of these matchups a unique number so they can be easily stored in a database and what not.  I've seen pairing functions, but I cannot find one in which order doesn't matter.  For example, I want the unique number for 2 and 17 to be the same as 17 and 2.  Is there an equation that will satisfy this?

Comment: Determining which of two values is smaller and swapping them such that e.g. the smallest is always first is usually quite straightforward to implement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hmm I didn't think of that.  That seems like it would actually solve my problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what programming language you are using.

In Java for example it would be quite easy, because *same seed* is producing the same random number sequence. So you could simple use the sum of both random numbers

```
 Long seed = 2L + 17L;
 Long seed2 = 17L+2L;
 Random random = new Random(seed);
 Random random2 = new Random(seed2);

 Boolean b = (random.nextLong() == random2.nextLong()) //true
```

However, this would also return the same value for `1+18`, `0+19` and so on - whatever sums up to 19.

So, to get really unique numbers "per pair" you would need to shift one of them. IE, with 117 entries, you could multiply the SMALLER (or larger) by 1000:

```
Long seed = 2L * 1000 + 17L;
....
```

Then you have a unique random number for 2,17 and 17,2 - but 19,0 or 0,19 would produce a DIFFERENT random number.

ps.: if it should ALWAYS return the same for 2,19 - the result is not really a random number, isn't it?

Comment: "the result is not really a random number" - since the OP doesn't use the word random, at all, in their question, I wonder why you focus so much on randomness in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question dates from 2014, but I still wanted to add the following answer.
You could use the product of prime numbers to do this. For example, if your pair is (2,4), then you could use the product of the 2nd prime number (=3) and the 4th prime number (=7) as your id (= 3*7 = 21).

In order to do this though with your 117 possible combinations, you would need to pre-calculate all first 117 prime numbers and store them for example in an array or a hash table and then do something like (in JavaScript):

```
var primes = [2,3,5,7,...];
var a = 2;
var b = 17;
var id = primes[a-1]*primes[b-1];
```

Note that if you want to decode them as well, things are going to be more difficult since you would need to calculate the prime factorization of your id.